# Use injectable dependencies in an angular module

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-dependency-injection, ngrx-reducers

I'm trying to generate generic reducers and actions of ngrx in Angular. I've already managed to do it but I have to apply the singelton pattern manually to generate the actions and reducers.

```
class CertificateGroupReducer extends CommonReducer<CertificateGroup, CertificateGroupState> {
  private static instance: CertificateGroupReducer;

  private constructor() {
    super('certificate-groups', certificateGroupActions, initialState, otherReducers);
  }

  public static getInstance(): CertificateGroupReducer {
    if (!CertificateGroupReducer.instance) {
      CertificateGroup.instance = new CertificateGroup();
    }
    return CertificateGroup.instance;
  }
}
export const certificateGroupReducer: CertificateGroup = CertificateGroup.getInstance();
```

This way I can import the instance and use it in the module to use it as param of StoreModule.forFeature()

```
import { certificateGroupReducer } from '../../certificate-groups/state/certificate-group.reducer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    EffectsModule.forFeature([CertificateGroupEffect]),
    StoreModule.forFeature(
      'certificate-groups',
      certificateGroupReducer.reducer, // <-- HERE!!
    ),
  ],
})
export class CertificateGroupsStateModule {}
```

Now I'm trying to use Angular's dependency pattern to handle object creation itself.

I've tried with the new function "inject()" but it doesn't seem to be usable in that context.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    EffectsModule.forFeature([CertificateGroupEffect]),
    StoreModule.forFeature('certificate-groups', inject(CertificateGroupReducer).reducer), // <- HERE!!
  ],
})
export class CertificateGroupsStateModule {}
```

**Module using Inetable() instead of manual Singelton**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CertificateGroupReducer extends CommonReducer<CertificateGroup, CertificateGroupState> {
  constructor(private certificateGroupActions: CertificateGroupActions) {
    super('certificate-groups', certificateGroupActions, initialState, otherReducers);
  }
}
```

**Versions**

1. Angular: 15.0.0
2. NGRX: 15.4.0

Is there a way to fix this, or as angular is thinking is impossible to do?

Comment: Sorry didn´t get your question. In any case singleton only means that there is only one instance for whole system, it doesn´t mean that service should be **provided in root**. Right now you are providing reducer twice.